# Working With ViewData in Razor Pages - set key globally for a page

Tags: c#, .net-core, razor-pages

Is there a way to set a ViewData key globally on page?
In my example, I have to set it on each verb.

On [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) or [this probably unofficial](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/viewdata) **but better** documentation I didn't find anything on this matter.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class PasswordResetModel : PageModel {

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<PasswordResetModel> _logger;
    private readonly IRecaptchaService _recaptchaService;
    private readonly RecaptchaOptions _recaptchaOptions;

    public PasswordResetModel(IConfiguration configuration, 
                              ILogger<PasswordResetModel> logger,
                              IRecaptchaService recaptchaService) {

        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
        _recaptchaService = recaptchaService;
        _recaptchaOptions = new RecaptchaOptions();
        _configuration.Bind("reCAPTCHA", _recaptchaOptions);

        //ViewData["ping"] = "pong"; -- here is not possible
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public PasswordResetRequest passwordResetRequest { get; set; }

    public void OnGet() {
        ViewData["IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset"] = _recaptchaOptions.IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {
        ViewData["IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset"] = _recaptchaOptions.IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset;
        //code skipped intentionally 
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the [ViewData] attribute:

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/viewdata#viewdata-attribute

This will make the property strongly typed and populated automatically.  I am not sure what data type "IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset" is, but I assumed string below:

```
[ViewData]
public string IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset { get; set; }
```

In your Razor page, you will then be able to access the property using either:

```
@ViewData["IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset"]
@Model.IsRecaptcaEnabledOnPasswordReset
```